# How can I find values of m so that the function $\frac{-m+x^2+x-4}{4 x-m}$ increasing in the interval $(1,2)$?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I am trying to find value of marameters $m$ so that the function  $f(x) = \dfrac{-m+x^2+x-4}{4 x-m}$ increasing in the interval $(1,2)$?

I tried

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] = (-4 - m + x + x^2)/(-m + 4 x);
Simplify[f'[x]]
g[x_] = Expand[Numerator[Simplify[f'[x]]]]
```

I know that, the function  $f(x) = \dfrac{-m+x^2+x-4}{4 x-m}$ increasing in the interval $(1,2)$ when and only when $g(x) = 16 + 3 m - 2 m x + 4 x^2 \geqslant 0$ for all $x$ in $(1,2)$ and $m/4 \notin (1,2)$. How can I get the values of $m$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done, making use of the definition of an increasing function and quantifiers or/and `FunctionMonotonicity`.

```
f[x_] = (-4 - m + x + x^2)/(-m + 4  x); 
Resolve[ForAll[{x1, x2}, x1 > 1 && x1 < 2 && x2 > 1 && x2 < 2, 
Implies[x2 > x1, f[x2] > f[x1]]], Reals]
```

> `-20 <= m <= 4 || 8 <= m <= 32`

```
FunctionMonotonicity[{(-4 - m + x + x^2)/(-m + 4  x),
 x > 1 && x < 2}, x] // FullSimplify
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1,  m \[Element] Reals && (-20 <= m < 4 || 8 < m <= 32)]`

Comment: There is a deficiency in the result of `FunctionMonotonicity`, It should be `-20 <= m <= 4 || 8 <= m <= 32` there.

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer following your idea of studying $f^\prime(x)>0$.

```
f[x_] = (-4 - m + x + x^2)/(-m + 4 x);
g[x_] := Derivative[1][f][x];
Reduce[{g[x] > 0, 1 <= x <= 2}, {m, x}]
```

It produces four results, only two valid for any $1\leq x \leq 2$, which are:

```
(-20 < m < 4 && 1 <= x <= 2) ||(8 < m < 32 && 1 <= x <= 2)
```

However, I don't know how to eliminate the two unwanted solutions...

Comment: `f[x_] = (-4 - m + x + x^2)/(-m + 4 x);Reduce[ForAll[x, x > 1 && x < 2, Derivative[1][f][x] >= 0], m]` does the job.