# How can I simplify this out put?

Tags: functions, parametric-functions

Based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/301158/how-can-i-find-values-of-m-so-that-the-function-frac-mx2x-44-x-m-incre), I tried to find the condition to function $y = \dfrac{a x+ b}{c x +d}$ where $ad \neq 0$ and $a d - b c \neq 0$ increasing on $(-d/c, +\infty)$. I tried

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] = (a  x + b)/(c  x + d );
Reduce[ForAll[x, x > -d/c, Derivative[1][f][x] > 0], {a, b, c, d}]
```

I know that, the answer is $a d - bc > 0$. How can I get this result?

Comment: One obstruction (it seems) is that `Reduce` is oriented toward solving for variables, not expressions. So it determines the solutions for three cases for `a`, namely `a<0`, `a==0`, and `a>0`. It's hard to put those cases back together, since those cases are solved for `b`, `c`, `d` in turn in a similar way resulting in their own sub-cases. I doubt this is what you want but it gives the desired result: `Or @@ Select[! Eliminate[Derivative[1][f][x] == 0, {x}] /. {{Unequal -> Less}, {Unequal ->Greater}}, Reduce[Implies[#, ForAll[x, x != -d/c, Derivative[1][f][x] > 0]], Reals] &]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to organize logical expressions to what one wnats to see. What I see is at best is

```
FullSimplify[ LogicalExpand[Reduce[ForAll[x, x > -d/c, f'[x] > 0], {a, b, c, d}]]]
```

$$(b|c|d)\in \mathbb{R}\land ((a=0\land ((c>0\land b<0)\lor (b>0\land c<0)))\lor (b c<a d\land a\neq 0))$$